# Doctor died, how to reschedule appointments with SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am really new to SQL i hope this is an understandable question. I am doing a little project for myself, i go from problem to problem trying to learn new things. i have made a Access file which i update trough SQL with c#.

Before a doctor is removed from the database i want to reschedule his existing appointments to other doctors that have time at the date of the original appointment.

**My APPOINTMENT table has the following columns in it:
ID_Appointments, ID_Doctor, ID_Patient, Date, Time and a column notes.**

**For the ID_Patient value i will be using the table ID_Patient, vice versa for the Doctor value.**

I've been looking into updating the ID_Doctor value with this of another doctor that does not have an appointment at the given data and time but creating the code out of scratch is hard for me and with a little help i hope to understand it much sooner.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider SQL Server Express instead of Access. http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/ Or MySQL. http://www.mysql.com/

Comment: <FriendlyReminder>It kinda sounds like you've taken patient data and put it on your local machine in an access DB. Please make sure all local data is encrypted and try to find a server to host your DB.</FriendlyReminder>

Comment: I don't understand all the suggestions that Access/Jet/ACE is not perfectly adequate. There is no information whatsoever in the question that indicates anything at all about the volume of data involved, nor the context in which it is being used (e.g., whether HIPAA complicance is involved). Lose the anti-Access bigotry, folks -- it makes you look foolish when you respond to questions that haven't been asked and have no real justification for doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is all theory (certainly better ways to do this in a high volume DB!!).
But for learning SQL the following should do the trick.

```
UPDATE a
SET ID_Doctor = (SELECT TOP 1 ID_Doctor FROM ID_Doctor d
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Appointment da
                                   WHERE da.ID_Doctor = d.ID_Doctor
                                   AND da.Date = a.Date AND da.Time = a.Time)
                )
FROM Appointment a
WHERE a.ID_Doctor = <The ID of the Doctor who Died>
```

Explination:
It Updates your Appointment table (alias: a)  where the Appointments are for the ID of the doctor that died.
It sets the id of the doctor for those appointments, to be the first id of a doctor that has not got an appointment at that time.

Note: You could improve the sql by changing the line: da.Time = a.Time
to be more of a time range, so that you dont have appointments that are scheduled extremely close together.

Comment: +1, though you probably want to select `top 1 ID_Doctor from Doctors` instead of `top 1 from ID_Doctor`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I missed something.

Answer (score 3):

since this relates to a medical database, which has rather strong HIPAA regulations governing it when it comes to the code that accesses it, you may well want to leave this to a developer. also without even a scintilla of existing code, which you can't post anyeways because it belongs to a medical database, we have no starting point in helping you.

Comment: Is that true for all countries?

Comment: each country has it's own specific regulations, with HIPAA being America's, and Great Britan having a similar set of rules, but the vast majority of cotries have some basic protection of doctor/patient info that requires the standardized safety of the digital medical records.

Comment: so we assume it's a personal project. we make the (very possibly wrong) assumption that the project involves information concerning U.S. doctors/patients. we assume that his "personal project" sees daylight and someone breaches his code and gains acess to patient records. can he tell the Medical Board that it was a "learning project" as they yank the clinic's license to operate?

Comment: I still think your are being quite US-centric. "Doctor" could also cover dentists and such like that may not be governed by such stringent rules in the Netherlands, which is the country code given in Jan Willem's profile.

Comment: This is a learning exercise, not a question on US medical privacy laws.  Let's pretend the question reads: "Hair stylist out sick, how to reschedule appointments in SQL?"

Comment: There is no guarantee that HIPAA applies. I have a client whose database includes appointments with doctors and clinicians, and HIPAA does NOT apply. It ran with a Jet back end for over 10 years before I recently upsized it to SQL Server. Merely upsizing the data store does not magically make an application HIPAA compliant, so any suggestion that an Access app with a Jet/ACE back end is by definition not HIPAA compliant and that a different back end will resolve the issue is completely unwarranted.

Comment: -1 for the answer and +1 for @David-W-Fenton. If there is no PHI or PII there is no HIPAA concern. Doctor 123 left and Doctor 456 has lots of open time on his calendar, so move appointmets for patients 111, 222, and 333.

Answer (score 3):

To replace doctor 42 on all of his appointments, try:

```
update  Appointments
set     ID_Doctor = 
        (
        select  top 1 ID_Doctor
        from    Doctors d
        where   d.Alive = 1
                and not exists
                (
                select  *
                from    Appointments a
                where   d.ID_Doctor = a.ID_Doctor
                        and Appointments.Time = a.Time
                )
        )
where   ID_Doctor = 42
        and PatientSignedImmunityFormForInjuriesCausedByUntestedSQL = 1
```

(Disclaimer: don't use SO code for medical production software, lol)

Answer (score 1):

You say Access, but are you using Jet or is Access itself installed? if it is, you can use the query design window to set up sample queries and then switch to SQL View to see how they work. The SQL strings from this should be usable in c# with very little modification. I would expect something like:

```
UPDATE Appointments SET ID_Doctor = 2 
WHERE ID_Doctor = 1
```